# Python - Send Messages Upon User Joining

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, I am trying in the latest version of Discord.Py and Python 3.6.4 to detect when a user joins, it will send a message to them welcoming them. My code is as follows:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.send_message(member,"Welcome!")
```

This code doesn't seem to work, I have looked up already on how others did it but the code is outdated, couldn't find anything on the API either on how I would do this. Any help is appreciated!

MAJOR EDIT: Okay, so the code works fine but I'm getting a 403 Permissions Error. The Bot was re-invited with FULL PERMISSIONS and in server has FULL PERMISSIONS. So I have no idea why this is happening. The bot can send messages anytime anywhere but not specifically under the on_memer_join(member) ... why?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work". Do you get any errors? Also, which discord.py are you using, rewrite or async? Check the version

Comment: I am using version: 0.16.2 (I uh, assume ASync) I just ran pip install Discord.Py

Answer (score 3):

[discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) is going through a bit of a metamorphosis at the moment.  There's the "async" branch, with version number 0.16, and there's the "rewrite" branch, version number 1.0, that isn't quite finished but many have started using anyways.   To find out which you're using, just try running

```
import discord
print(discord.__version__)
```

The code you posted looks good for the "async" branch, so I suspect you're on the "rewrite" branch. Try

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Welcome!")
```

The documentation for the rewrite branch is [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/index.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me, it continues to give the error: 'Member' has no attribute 'send' (although I swear it does)

Comment: Did you figure out which version you are on?  What error did you original code give?

Comment: It Gives Me a 403 Permissions Denied Error.. 'Cannot Send messages to this user'  version 0.16.12

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. When you added the bot to the server, you didn't give it the permissions necessary to send private messages. Remove the bot from the server and add it again with the correct permissions.

Comment: How do I give it permissions? If you mean in the server, it totally has permissions. I tried re-inviting it but it doesn't ask for any permissions, do I need to write some code?

Answer (score 1):

For the Rewritten version of Discord.py, You need to enable Intents

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = Bot.commands(command_prefix = '', intents = intents)

async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Welcome!')
```

You must enable intents in your bot application as well.
Sorry this is a late comment.