# discord.py sending a new server member a direct message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my code is:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot ready")

    async def on_member_join(member):
        await member.send("nice to see u on the server")

client = MyClient()
client.run(My token)
```

But the message isn't sent. Maybe someone can send me a correct and working code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Send Messages Upon User Joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800430/python-send-messages-upon-user-joining)

Comment: You need the members [intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) enabled to receive on_member_join events

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, however you could have found easier results by looking it up. A good source to get started is https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/ where it also answers your question.

```
#@bot or #@client
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, #message'
    )
```

Comment: That's not really the issue here, `Member.send` internally calls `Member.create_dm` and `Member.dm_channel.send`

Comment: In addition to what @ŁukaszKwieciński said, it is better if you use try except since some members don't allow DMs which will make an error and if you are using an error handler it will catch it.